# Cleaning percentage column (decimal + whole number) in Python with whole number

Tags: python, percentage

I have a column of percentages which contains numbers like `0.4567 , 0.1564 , 19 , 23, 0 , 0.1234` where I require a normalization to whole numbers i.e. `45 , 15, 19 ,23 , 0 , 12` as such. I have reproduced an example as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n_row =  10
dicti = {'id':[coli for coli in range(1,(n_row+1))],
     'perc_col':[30,0.4546,0.76543223190,10,0,0.29567,93,15,0.31,0.456]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dicti)
df
```

> **Data Frame Output**

[image]

> **Expected Output**
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normalise the unnormalised dataframe column and convert to integer (per your question) with:

```
df['perc_col'] = df['perc_col'].apply(lambda x : int(x) if x > 1 else int(100*x))
```

Output

```
   id  perc_col
0   1        30
1   2        45
2   3        76
3   4        10
4   5         0
5   6        29
6   7        93
7   8        15
8   9        31
9  10        45
```

Per your comments, if you have `NaN` values and want to leave them unchanged, you cannot convert the column to int. You can leave it as float but change to whole numbers as follows:

```
df['perc_col'] = df['perc_col'].apply(lambda x : x//1 if x > 1 else 100*x//1)
```

Output this time (changing the last value in the initial dictionary to `np.nan`) is:

```
   id  perc_col
0   1      30.0
1   2      45.0
2   3      76.0
3   4      10.0
4   5       0.0
5   6      29.0
6   7      93.0
7   8      15.0
8   9      31.0
9  10       NaN
```

To meet your second additional requirement of handling strings, you can essentially ignore strings if you change the command to:

```
df['perc_col'] = df['perc_col'].apply(lambda x : x if isinstance(x, str) else (x//1 if x > 1 else 100*x//1))
```

Comment: i have NaN in that also  and i am getting error as `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` .

Comment: You don't have NaN in your example... What would you want NaN to convert to?

Comment: NaN should be as it is .i will change the data frame in dictionary

Comment: still i am getting error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: There are strings in your column as well? You should provide a representative example of your actual data. I've already answered your initial question, and your revised question including NaNs

Comment: i have 15lakh observation how can i identify those rows .thats difficult

Comment: I added code to leave strings unaltered but only normalise other strings. Hopefully you don't have anything else to worry about. If you do, you can adjust the conditions.